# Como ocultar a barra de navegação?

Tags: java, android

Eu usei esse código abaixo para ocultar a barra de navegação Android. O código funcionou, mas quando uma nova activity é aberta por um botão do app a barra aparece e sai rapidamento, isso não fica muito bom. Então eu gostaria de saber como melhorar ou mudar esse código de modo que a barra apenas apareçam quando for chamada.

```
// Atributo

    protected View decorView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.mundo1_fase1_0);

        decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if (visibility == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(hideSystemBars());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Método onWindowFocusChanged

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(hideSystemBars());
        }
    }

    // Método hideSystemBars

    protected int hideSystemBars() {
        return View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }
```

Comment: Não entendo pq negativaram!

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar isto no tema da sua aplicação

```xml
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```